# Z-index isn't working for L.tileLayer

Tags: leaflet, wms, z-index

I am having difficulty with layer order. I have 4 layers but `zIndex` is not working for `L.tileLayer`. Here's a part of  my code: https://pastecode.xyz/view/d726ccb1

```
 var overlay_Numerydziaek1 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/pub/guest/G2_GO_WMS/MapServer/WMSServer', {
    layers: 'NumeryDzialek',
    opacity: 1.0,
    format: 'image/png8',
    transparent: false,
    continuousWorld : true,
    zIndex:110,
}).addTo(map);


var overlay_Dziaki2 = L.tileLayer.wms('http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/pub/guest/G2_GO_WMS/MapServer/WMSServer', {
    layers: 'Dzialki',
    format: 'image/png',
    uppercase: true,
    transparent: false,
    continuousWorld : true,
    tiled: true,
    info_format: 'text/html',
    opacity: 1,
    zIndex:100,
    identify: false,    
});

map.addLayer(overlay_Dziaki2);  
overlay_Dziaki2.bringToFront()
var overlay_googlemapsstelita_1 = L.tileLayer('http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    opacity: 1.0
    zIndex:50,
});
var overlay_OpenStreetMap_1 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    opacity: 1.0,
    zIndex:10,
});
map.addLayer(overlay_OpenStreetMap_1);
overlay_OpenStreetMap_1.bringToBack()
```

With this code var **`overlay_googlemapsstelita_1`** appears on top 
and the second is `var overlay_OpenStreetMap_1`.
Then `var overlay_Numerydziaek1` and `var overlay_Dziaki2`.
I want `overlay_Numerydziaek1` to appear on top.
How can I do this ? 
For other non `L.tileLayer`, `zIndex` is working fine.

Comment: I've been also trying
   overlay_OpenStreetMap_1.setZIndex(100); 
but still not working :(

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, post it as an answer, please, and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3):

First off, adding Google Maps tiles via a tile template [goes against Google's terms of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672846/how-to-load-a-google-maps-baselayer-in-leaflet-after-june-2018/50675567#50675567). I encourage you to have a look at [GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/).

Second: calls to `bringToFront` will change the `z-index` of the tilelayers. Dig a bit into [Leaflet's source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/59a2d7504adf96b6469b2fc7d70ebf673747e6e8/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L180). Calls to `bringToFront` and `bringToBack` will change the `z-index` of the `TileLayer` **based on the `TileLayer`s currently added to the map**.

Third: See the [Leaflet tutorial on map panes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/) for info on how to have finer control of different kinds of layers. Quoting from there:

```
map.createPane('labels');
map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB',
        pane: 'labels'
}).addTo(map);
```

You might want to add your WMS layers to a different pane which will always be on top of tilelayers in the default pane.